# Copy the list of principal user to arraylist to use arraylist.indexof. VB.net

Tags: vb.net

What I am doing is iterating through all the groups that belong to the top group (Generic reports). Then I take advantage of the `GroupPrincipal.GetMembers(True)` which will recurse through a given group name. I test to see if the user exits under that group and if true I put the group name in an arraylist.

I use the for each principal in `GroupPrincipal.GetMembers` to loop through each returned user to see if they exist.

Is there a way to put all the returned users `Principal.Name` from a given group in `GroupPrincipal.GetMembers` into an `ArrayList`? This would allow me to to use `Arraylist1.IndexOf` to search for user. Which would be much faster then iterating through a returned list using the for each construct.

Thanks.

```
Sub RetAllMbrs(strUser As String)
    Dim oPC As PrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext() '<- this is function somewhere else in the code
    Dim grp1 As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPC, IdentityType.Name, "Generic Reports")    ' return all groups under cr reports
    Dim usr As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPC, IdentityType.Name, "Joe User")
    strUser = usr.SamAccountName
    Dim al_GrpList As New ArrayList

    For Each gp As Principal In grp1.Members
      Dim strGroup As String = gp.Name
      If strGroup.Substring(0, 10).ToLower = "generic reports" Then  'only do groups
        Dim grp2 As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPC, IdentityType.Name, strGroup)    'return all items under group
        For Each p As Principal In grp2.GetMembers(True)    'recurse group and see if user present 
          Dim strSamAcct As String = p.SamAccountName
          If strSamAcct.ToLower = strUser.ToLower Then
            al_GrpList.Add(strGroup)
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        grp2.Dispose()
      End If
    Next
    oPC.Dispose()
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logic in your loop, I don't think that you would gain any benefit from moving the grp1 members into a different construct because the grp2 members are based on the grp1 name.